# c# split string with long space or tabs

Tags: c#, winforms

I have string like this

```
 string asd = "PT. Mitra Adiperkasa Tbk                                    01.710.880.4-054.000                                        Wisma 46 Kota BNI Lt. 8                                     Jl Jend Sudirman Kav 1, Jak Pus     "
```

with really long space

how can I divide each sentence into a different string
like this

```
string asd1 = "PT. Mitra Adiperkasa Tbk"
string asd2 = "01.710.880.4-054.000" 
string asd3 = "Wisma 46 Kota BNI Lt. 8"
string asd4 = "Jl Jend Sudirman Kav 1, Jak Pus"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  string abc = "abc    def    ghi";
        string[]xyz= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(abc, @"\s{2,}");
        System.Console.WriteLine(xyz[0]);
        System.Console.WriteLine(xyz[1]);
```

Try using this code

Answer (score 2):

How about like this? Split by 2 spaces or a tab.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string asd = "PT. Mitra Adiperkasa Tbk                                    01.710.880.4-054.000                                        Wisma 46 Kota BNI Lt. 8                                     Jl Jend Sudirman Kav 1, Jak Pus     ";
        foreach (string s in asd.Trim().Split(new string[] { "  ", "    " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: glad to know that. but the results may not be stable. depending your strings different kinds of separators.