# How to get words (word by word) in a string with different spaces?

Tags: .net, string, vb.net

I need to get the words in a string but the problem is, it has a different type of spacing (there is a space, double space, tab) Here's the sample type of string I have:

```
label1.text = "119  2019-02-20 09:26:30 1   0   1   0"
```

I need a result like this

```
labeloutput1.text = "119"
labeloutput2.text = "2019-02-20"
labeloutput3.text = "09:26:30"
labeloutput4.text = "1"
labeloutput5.text = "0"
labeloutput6.text = "1"
labeloutput7.text = "0"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# split string with long space or tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882741/c-sharp-split-string-with-long-space-or-tabs)

Comment: By tagging a multitude of languages, which can't all be applicable to your question, it makes it very difficult to provide a relevant answer. A VBA answer will be quite different to a VB.NET answer, and a VB.NET answer will be a little different to a C# answer. Why have you used all of these tags? Were you searching for the [`language-agnostic`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info) tag instead?

Comment: Assuming that you mean to use C#, Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani's answer is the correct one. In VBA or VB.NET, it would be a bit different.

Comment: Sorry, im just a newbie. forgive me :(

Comment: No worries :) Just remember that being specific helps us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)` overload of `string.Split()` you can remove empty entries:

```cs
string[] result = label1.Replace('\t', ' ').Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You may also split and then remove empty ones yourself:

```cs
string[] result = label1.Text.Replace('\t', ' ').Split(' ').Where(x => x != "").ToArray();
```

Comment: You'd need to include the `Tab` character in that array, based on the question.

Answer (score 1):

This applies if you want to use VB.NET:

Either:

```vb
Dim result As String() = label1.Replace(vbTab, " "c).Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

or:

```cs
Dim result As String() = label1.Text.Replace(vbTab, " "c).Split(" "c).Where(Function(x) x <> "").ToArray()
```

This is Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani's answer ported to VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

While @Ashkan solution works fine, I think you can omit the `.Replace('\t', ' ')`. No need to replace those extra big whitespaces (tabs), since you're explicitly removing them  with the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

I would simply do;

```
string[] result = label1.text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or if you prefer Regex;

```
var result = Regex.Split(label1.text, @"\s+").Where(s => s != string.Empty).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you want (VBA):

```vb
Dim input, splitResult, i
input = "119 2019-02-20 09:26:30 1   0   1   0"

input = Replace(input, chr(9), " ") ' replace tab with space
Do While Instr(input, "  ") > 0 ' keep looping until there are no double spaces
    input = Replace(input, "  ", " ") ' replace double space with space
Loop

splitResult = Split(input, " ") ' split by space

For i = 0 to Ubound(splitResult) ' loop through the result
    MsgBox splitResult(i)
Next
```

Results in:

```
119
2019-02-20
09:26:30
1
0
1
0
```

Comment: No problemo! :)